# Looking for a way to detect my own hosts in a private network

Tags: networking, network-discovery

I'm looking for a way to detect my own hosts (e.g. two notebooks or notebook and raspberry pi) in a private network (e.g. at the house of a friend).

In my mind there are some options to do so:

- write a deamon to broadcast the information
- write a script with some ARP requests with the mac address
- et cetera

But I have no idea if something like this exists, or if I have to write it by myself.

One scenario this could be used for is: I bring my raspi and my notebook to a friends house, connect both hosts to his network and now I don't want to add a monitor to the raspi and look up the address and I don't have access to the router so I can't look into the dhcp lease table.

Any ideas or hints?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See if [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/86193) can help you

Comment: For implement something like what I want `arping` will be a nice tool. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use a tool like nmap(https://serverfault.com/questions/148113/can-i-use-nmap-be-use-to-discover-ips-and-mac-addresses) or if you want to use a smartphone/tablet download an app like Fing, or you can simply reference it using its hostname(ex. ssh ACCOUNT@RPIHOSTNAME.local).

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what [mDNS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6762) is intended for. You didn't specify your operating systems, but on Linux, this is implemented by the Avahi daemon, and on Mac, by the Bonjour service. Windows has its own protocol ([LLMNR](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4795)) which isn't compatible with mDNS.

Comment: This works in my own network or in well configured networks, but not at every network. This bad configured router/modem/wifi-aps from all the different isps doesn't work well with mDNS.